# undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'

Tags: qt, arm, cross-compiling

I'm cross compiling Qt program to U-touch using `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.
When I execute the following command, I get the error message below:

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o try main.cpp -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -lQtCore -lQtGui
```

Error Message:

```
/opt/poky/1.2.1/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.6.4/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
/opt/poky/1.2.1/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.6.4/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler (or better, the linker) cannot find a copy of the libraries to link to.

Solution:

1. Put a copy of the Qt libraries for the target on the host.
2. Then, provide their path to gcc with the **-L /path/** option.